# Problems installing Opencv 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.0

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, opencv

I'm having problems trying to install OpenCV 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. When I want to install the dependencies I got the following problem:

```
andres@andres-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev cmake libswscale-dev libjasper-dev
[sudo] password for andres:
Reading package lists...
Done Building dependency tree  Reading state information...
Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been
moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the
situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libtiff4-dev : Depends: libtiff5-dev (> 4.0.3-6~) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I want to install OpenCV 2.0 because there is an old project that uses that version of OpenCV.

**Update 1**

1: I installed libtiff5-dev but then it threw another error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg62-dev but 6b1-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Then I removed libjpeg-turbo8-dev but it uninstalled libtiff5-dev. Someone posted about the problem like 4 years ago without a solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1985957

**Update 2**

I used aptitude instead of apt-get to install the dependencies. Everything went ok but I checked that I have ffmpeg and v4l as no. I didn't care and I tried to compile the library. I got the following compilation errors:

```
In file included from ../include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123:0,
                 from cxcore/_cxcore.h:60,
                 from cxcore/cxprecomp.cpp:43:
../include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:169:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
     typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
             ^
In file included from ../include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2243:0,
                 from ../include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from cxcore/_cxcore.h:60,
                 from cxcore/cxprecomp.cpp:43:
../include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:1916:15: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
 static inline ptrdiff_t operator - (const FileNodeIterator& it1, const FileNodeIterator& it2)
               ^
../include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp:2465:31: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name a type
 template<typename _Tp> inline ptrdiff_t operator - (const SeqIterator<_Tp>& a,
                               ^
In file included from ../include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2244:0,
                 from ../include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from cxcore/_cxcore.h:60,
                 from cxcore/cxprecomp.cpp:43:
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp: In member function ‘void cv::Mat::locateROI(cv::Size&, cv::Point&) const’:
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:356:5: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
     ptrdiff_t delta1 = data - datastart, delta2 = dataend - datastart;
     ^
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:356:5: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/utility:68:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:60,
                 from ../include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:51,
                 from ../include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from cxcore/_cxcore.h:60,
                 from cxcore/cxprecomp.cpp:43:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:187:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits/c++config.h:187:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../include/opencv/cxcore.hpp:2244:0,
                 from ../include/opencv/cxcore.h:2123,
                 from cxcore/_cxcore.h:60,
                 from cxcore/cxprecomp.cpp:43:
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:356:15: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘delta1’
     ptrdiff_t delta1 = data - datastart, delta2 = dataend - datastart;
               ^
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:358:9: error: ‘delta1’ was not declared in this scope
     if( delta1 == 0 )
         ^
../include/opencv/cxmat.hpp:367:31: error: ‘delta2’ was not declared in this scope
     wholeSize.height = (int)((delta2 - minstep)/step + 1);
                               ^
make[2]: *** [cxprecomp.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/andres/OpenCV-2.0.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/andres/OpenCV-2.0.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` first? Both `libtiff4-dev` (4.0.3-7ubuntu0.3) and `libtiff5-dev` (4.0.3-7ubuntu0.3) are happily installed on my 14.04 system

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with more problems that I'm facing.

Comment: OpenCV-2.0.0 appears to configure OK for me **with** `libjpeg-turbo8-dev` but **without** `libjpeg62-dev`: I suggest you try removing that package from the prerequisite list and seeing if you can configure the build anyhow

Comment: I did it and I get the compilation errors that I inserted at the end of my original question.

Comment: Try editing the package's include/opencv/cxcore.hpp file and adding `#include <cstddef>` to its list of standard headers: see here http://code.opencv.org/issues/1028

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks @steeldriver. I faced other problems but I solved them with the help of this webpage: https://tranthithanhhuyenbk.wordpress.com/2013/08/

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on fresh installed Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, and both give almost the same error. Error regarding `ibjpeg-turbo8-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg62-dev`.

If you are using virtual machine and you are **not afraid to damage it** you could try run this command. Accept everything that `aptitute` will suggest and proceed with result.

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev cmake libswscale-dev libjasper-dev
```

**Update**

After installation via aptitude OP get the compilation problem. This problem is solved by @steeldriver suggestion in comments:

> Try editing the package's include/opencv/cxcore.hpp file and adding `#include <cstddef>` to its list of standard headers: see here http://code.opencv.org/issues/1028

Comment: I followed your instructions but I don't know if it worked or not because when I configured the compilation it reported ffmpeg and v4l as no.  How I can get ffmpeg and v4l as yes?

Comment: I got compilation errors. I updated my question.

Comment: @user702475 user steeldriver gave you nice solution in the comments. Did you tried it? Do you have some troubles with this?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. After that, everything worked well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @andrestoga, thanks for response. I will update answer, don't forget about other guys with the same problem.